# Firebase realtime DB - limitations of paths and keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Realtime DB, what are the limits on:

- keys
- paths
- nesting level

?

Meaning restrictions on lengths as well as disallowed/special chars/values.
And any other restrictions (or discouragements) there might be.

Is [this deprecated pre-Google-integration document (link here)](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html) still up to date?

> Length of a key: 768 bytes
>
> Depth of child nodes: 32

I don't see max path length mentioned there.

What is the non-deprecated location for this documentation?

I cannot find an equivalent in https://firebase.google.com/docs/ .
As if some of the docs "got lost in the shuffle"...

Thanks for any hints.

EDIT: I've broadened it slightly - not just lengths but any restrictions that might apply.

Comment: Yes, that information is still up to date. The [disallowed characters in a key are listed in the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree). I don't think there is a hard-coded limit on the path length. There probably is some limitation in each context that you use them, but there's no list for those values.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thank you. Perhaps this should be made to be the answer, then? Cheers.

Comment: So the table with the limitations has not [yet?] been transplanted to the new docs, right? (although I see that some of the info exists in some places in the docs). That table was actually quite nice. Any particular reason that it does not exist in the new docs?

Comment: We have an open task to add the info back, but somehow it never got implemented. If you have an idea of where you'd expect to find it in the new documentation, click the link at the top-right that says "Send Feedback" and ask for it to be added there.

Answer (score 5):

The Firebase documentation says 768 bytes is still the limit for a Key, and that they use UTF-8 encoding.  With UTF-8, a character is 1-4 bytes.

However, most characters are 1 byte, unless you use a character such as ♥, which is 3 bytes.  Therefore, for normal use of a key, the character limit is 768.  If you want to anticipate some outlandish characters, it may be best to be conservative and limit total characters to 500 ,600, or 700.  Depends on how you want to use the keys.

Test your characters and strings here:
https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

Documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) documentation mentions that firebase realtime database can be nested up to 32 levels. But as its mentioned there itself that it is not a good practice to nest your data. Denormalisation of data though seems redundant, it gives more flexibility when writing rules and when writing queries to the database.